# How to add a listener for a array list of java.util.List

Tags: java, arraylist, swt, onclicklistener, jface

I have created a array list and when the list item is selected using mouse down event a listener has to be added for it so how can this be done .The code for which i have created the array list ia as follows

```
final java.util.List<Object> listSort = new ArrayList<>();
for(String key: descriptionMappernewer.keySet())
    listSort.add(key);

final MyFilter filter = new MyFilter();

final ListViewer viewer = new ListViewer(this);
//viewer.getList();
viewer.getList().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
//viewer.getList();
viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
viewer.setInput(listSort);
```

and now I need to add mouse down event listener for it. Earlier I had written the mouse event listener of SWT but that has to changed now. The earlier SWT listener looks like this

```
list.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){
      public void handleEvent(Event e) {
          int index =  list.getSelectionIndex();
          txtMethodDescription.setText(descriptionMappernewer.get( list.getItem(index)));
      }
});
```

So please help me how can we add the listener to array list of java.util.List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.util.List` is not a user interface object and does not support listeners.

The user interface object in your code is the `ListViewer`. Since this is a JFace object it uses `addSelectionListener` for selections:

```
viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(final SelectionChangedEvent event)
    {
      IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)viewer.getSelection();

      txtMethodDescription.setText(descriptionMappernewer.get(selection.getFirstElement())));
    }
  });
```